# Build and Serve NestJS applications using full-icu of Node to use Internationalization

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, nestjs, intl

My intention is to use the [**Intl** API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) inside NestJS application. In order to do that, I need to use the **full-icu** package of NestJS. I wanted to know how can I do that.

I am finding it difficult to serve and build using **full-icu** using the CLI option --icu-data-dir=node_modules/full-icu

Any NestJS experts who are want to check this out can collaborate on this.

Thanks,
Ankit